# C# programs communicating by named pipes as service between 2 hosts

Tags: c#, service, named-pipes, windows-server-2012, local-system-account

How can 2 C# programs communicate with each other by named pipes.

If I run the program under a administrator account with elevated rights everything works.
I need to run this programs as a service with the account 'Local System' but then I have no network access.

Situation :

- Server : 1 program runs as a service on a Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
- Client : 1 program runs as a service on a client Windows 7, 8.1 or 10

On the server

- I put the name of named pipe in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters[NullSessionPipes]
    Restart the the service LanmanServer

In the server program I create the pipe as follow

```
PipeSecurity psobj = new PipeSecurity();
psobj.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("EveryOne", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
NamedPipeServerStream requestpipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(REQUESTPIPENAME, PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, 
                            PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 2048, 2048, psobj);
```

In the client program I connect to the named pipe as follow:

```
NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(SERVER, REQUESTPIPENAME, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.WriteThrough)
```

I simulated also the situation between 2 Windows 7 machines (1 physical and 1 virtual, not bridged). Here I tried some options in :

- Network access: Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and shares => Disabled
- Network access: Allow LocalSystem NULL session fallback => Enabled

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can't you give executable "Run As Admin" so it will work with normal users?

Comment: our users don't have admin rights.

Comment: An admin can set a executable to run as admin so normal users can run the executable with higher privilege.

Comment: for security reasons has this program to run as a service. User may not be able to kill the process

Comment: Services can be set to run as Admin also.

Comment: Password of the local account administrator changes randomly every 1 or 2 weeks

Comment: Once the Run as Admin is set on an executable file password isn't needed to run.